# What is the meaning of "Ring structure varying continuously with $x$?"

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, sheaf-theory

What does it mean when one states that a ring structure varies continuously with some variable? Say, in the following context

> The stalks may be rings, and in that case the ring structure of $\mathscr{F}_x$ is assumed to vary continuously with $x$. Or, each $\mathscr{F}_x$ may be a module over some fixed field.

taken from  Zariski's *[Scientific report on the second summer institute, several complex variables. Part III. Algebraic sheaf theory](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183520530).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sheaf of sets on a space $X$ is a topological space $\mathscr{F}$ together with a continuous map $p:\mathscr{F}\to X$ satisfying certain conditions (this is not the only way to define a sheaf, but it is the one Zariski is using).  If you put a ring structure on $\mathscr{F}_x=p^{-1}(\{x\})$ for each $x$, then to say this ring structure "varies continuously" just means that the ring operations are continuous maps (and similarly for any other sort of algebraic structure).  For instance, addition is a map $+:\{(a,b)\in\mathscr{F}\times\mathscr{F}:p(a)=p(b)\}\to\mathscr{F}$, and this map should be continuous (with respect to the product topology on the domain).  Similarly, multiplication should be continuous, negation should be continuous as a map $\mathscr{F}\to\mathscr{F}$, and the maps $0,1:X\to\mathscr{F}$ which send $x$ to the zero element or the unit element of $\mathscr{F}_x$ (respectively) should be continuous.

(The more common modern approach is to define a sheaf not in terms of the space $\mathscr{F}$ but rather in terms of the operation which takes an open set $U\subseteq X$ to the set $\mathscr{F}(U)$ of sections of the map $p$ over the set $U$, together with restriction maps $\mathscr{F}(U)\to\mathscr{F}(V)$ whenever $V\subseteq U$.  In this framework, it is automatic that any algebraic structure on the sets $\mathscr{F}(U)$ "varies continuously", in the sense that putting (for instance) a ring structure on each $\mathscr{F}(U)$ such that the restriction maps are homomorphisms is equivalent to putting a ring structure on each stalk $\mathscr{F}_x$ such that the ring operations are continuous as described above.)

Comment: What is an example of a discontinuous ring operation? What are the open sets in $\mathscr{F}$?

Comment: Well, if you just define a ring structure on each set $\mathscr{F}_x$ completely randomly, it probably won't be continuous.  There's no rule for what the open sets of $\mathscr{F}$ are; the topology on $\mathscr{F}$ is part of the data of the sheaf (it just has to satisfy that the map $p$ is a local homeomorphism).

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have a vector bundle on a manifold, in such a way that each fiber is a ring. Consider a local trivialization. In terms of it, you can describe the multiplication of each of those rings in terms of structure constants: that the structures of rings varies continuously means that those structure constants are continuous functions.

In other categories, like the holomorphic one or the algebraic one you adapt as needed.

Comment: But this quote is talking about general sheaves on a space (defined in terms of étalé spaces), rather than something like a vector bundle.

Comment: Well, @EricWofsey, that is precisely what comes packaged into the phrase «you adapt as needed»...