# What does it mean for algebraic operations to be continuous in a stalk?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Each stalk has a ring structure, and both algebraic operations (addition and multiplication) are continuous.

What does it mean for addition and multiplication to be continuous in the general sense? For example, let us consider the sheaf of continuous functions on $\Bbb{R}$, and let $I_0$ be the stalk at $x=0$. I understand how germs are closed under addition and multiplication here, and how these operations are well-defined. However, how do I interpret the fact that the addition and multiplication of germs in $I_0$ are continuous?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095222/what-is-the-meaning-of-ring-structure-varying-continuously-with-x

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez- I do not understand what structure constants here. I would be grateful if you could explain how the operations that I have specified are continuous. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The accepted answer there has nothign to do with structure constants. In any case: have you googled for what 'structure constants' are?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez (Lower level question) I'm reading that the operations on a normed space are continuous with respect to the norm. Has it interesting consequences? I've not seen applications of it...